# Modal UIAlertController in non async method with return type

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

I currently have a method I have to implement, that needs the exact signature. I cannot add `async`, since it returns `bool` and I can't make the return type `Task<bool>`. The method shows a modal UIAlertController and waits for the result. it needs to return the result once the UIAlertController has dismissed. Currently, the method doesn't work since `PresentViewController` is a blocking call. The UIAlertController never shows because of that, and the application is stuck there.

Here's the method:

```
public static bool ShowYesNoMessage(string title, string message)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    UIAlertController alertController = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Yes", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => tcs.TrySetResult(true)));
    alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("No", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => tcs.TrySetResult(false)));

    //Gets the currently visible view controller and present from this one
    UIHelper.CurrentViewController.PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);

    tcs.Task.Wait();
    return tcs.Task.Result;
}
```

Is there a way to keep the UI updating, while waiting for the result of the method in a blocking call like "ShowYesNoMessage"? Perhaps an iOS related method to prevent the UI from freezing the modal UIAlertController? Or maybe another method to present a modal view?

Comment: It's likely that it's deadlocked. Can you use [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and run the UIAlertController in another thread?

Comment: The thing is that the UIAlertController won't appear if it's put on another thread...

Comment: Use `InvokeOnMainThread` when presenting it.

Comment: I did, but when I do, I can't wait for the value to be chosen (yes/no). The method returns immediately...

Comment: Did you use `AutoResetEvent`? Can you update your question with the latest code?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how `AutoResetEvent` is supposed to help here... How would you integrate this in the above code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `WaitHandle` to wait until the user responds. Probably not the best workaround but should work.

```
public static bool ShowYesNoMessage(string title, string message)
{
    var resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    var result = false;

    // Run in another thread so it doesn't block
    Task.Run(action: () =>
    {
        var alertController = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        alertController.AddAction(
            UIAlertAction.Create(
                "Yes", 
                UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
                (action) => 
                {
                    result = true;
                    resetEvent.Set();
                }));

        alertController.AddAction(
            UIAlertAction.Create(
                "No", 
                UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
                (action) => 
                {
                    result = false;
                    resetEvent.Set();
                }));

        InvokeOnMainThread(() => UIHelper.CurrentViewController.PresentViewController(alertController, true, null));
    });

    resetEvent.WaitOne();

    return result;
}
```

**NOTE**: Code has not been tested

EDIT: The code probably will still block but let me know how it goes. I'm not near a mac so can't test it.

Comment: This will not work, you cannot call UI code in another thread that the main thread